# c# System.OutOfMemoryException: 'Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I get this System.OutOfMemoryException.
YES: I have added

```
<runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled = "true" />
</runtime>
```

to the `App.Config` file located in the project folder.
I have a 64-bit Windows 10, about 20GB free ram of my 32GB. Visual-Studio 2022.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEBbp.png)

I have also tried to set x64 everywhere I can inside Visual Studio.

The code that generates my Exception is:

```
List<int> dataList = new List<int>();
for (int j = 0; j < int.MaxValue - 10; j++)
{
    dataList.Add(j);
    if ((j %100000) == 0 )
    { Console.WriteLine(j.ToString("N0")); }
}
Console.WriteLine($"Total items in the List: {dataList.Count.ToString("N0")}. ");
```

The last printout on the console is:
2,146,400,000.
I never get to the part of writing `dataList.Count`.
What can be done to increase the memory allocated to  C# and/or Visual Studio?

Comment: Why do you want to have a List with 2 billion elements in it? An int is 4 bytes, so 2 billion ints gives 8 billion bytes. `List` uses a backing array which needs to be 8GB of contiguous memory, plus it is resized automatically, so you will have multiple arrays the size of several GBs in memory.

Comment: Could you check `Environment.Is64BitProcess`?

Comment: What is your goal? The count will be `int.MaxValue-10`. Remove the loop, change the last line to `Console.WriteLine("Total items in the List: {(int.MaxValue-10).ToString("N0")}. ")`

Comment: List will resize the internal Array if it exceeds its capacity so at some point you may need a multiple of the array size. Besides that you hit the ArraySize Limit https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,2d2b551eabe74985,references. Its a hard limit if you need something larger you can get it with gcAllowVeryLargeObjects  but not as Array/lList etc.

Comment: Changing the *solution platform* to x64 does not guarantee that you get the x64 jitter at runtime.  The proper platform for a .NET project is AnyCPU, reflecting the ability of .NET to run on any cpu.  Ask for a specific jitter at runtime with Project > Properties > Build, you need "Prefer 32-bit" = off and Platform Target = x64.  Repeat for the Release configuration.

Comment: The list implementation is backed by an array. What I think happens is that the backing array is 8GB in size and there is no more room. A new array with more space is created which is 2*8GB, and the existing elements are copied over. At this stage you will need at least 8GB + 16GB => 24GB free.

Comment: You would not only need the 24GB you also would need the 16GB as a **continuous** block and that in a somewhat fragmented memory. Among others things because of resizing the List over and over again.

Comment: Almost every time an OOM occurs it's due to code like this. There are huge performance differences too - the code you used allocates 32 temporary buffers and copies the data from one to the next. The first 31 buffers will have to be GCd at some point, causing a huge delay in the application. Specifying a `capacity` in the constructor will reduce or even eliminate reallocations and waste

Comment: Thank you for your comments and information. I'm a newbie when it comes to programming. First of: Yes Environment.Is64BitProcess : "True". in my program. The same goes for the check of the properties: Prefer32-bit is off, and Platformtaret: x64. Do I understand you correct that it would work if I had more than 24GB+16GB free? Or is it a hard limit of max array-length of "0X7FEFFFFF" or "2,146,435,071" items? But  it is very good inputs and answers to my question.

Comment: @Tommy you'd have the *same* problem in any language, including C++. Production libraries use buffers whenever possible instead of pointers because the data can be loaded into the CPU cache and accessed in the fastest way possible. Dereferencing pointers eg in a linked list would *invalidate* cache entries and try to access RAM at far lower speeds.

Comment: `Do I understand you correct that it would work if I had more than 24GB+16GB free?` no. It would work if you specified a large `capacity`. If `int.MaxValue` works, go for it. You'd only have to allocate the buffer *once*, using no extra data

Comment: @Tommy if you used a `std::vector` in C++ the same way you did here you'd encounter the *same* problem, because `vector` also uses an internal buffer that gets doubled when full.

Answer (score 4):

> The last printout on the console is: 2,146,400,000.

The `List<T>` type uses a doubling algorithm to manage capacity. Each time it reaches capacity, it allocates a new internal array twice the size of the old one, and then manually copies the elements from the old array to the new.

So the first thing we learn is, when you know the final size (as you do here), letting the list grow itself is incredibly inefficient. Instead, construct the list with the desired capacity in mind:

```
var listSize = int.MaxValue - 10;
var dataList = new List<int>(listSize);
for (int j = 0; j < listSize; j++)
```

This will not only save the extra allocations, but also save all that work copying elements between buffers. And it tells you up front (via exception) if you're gonna run out of RAM, instead of making the computer do a bunch of work before finally failing.

The second thing we should notice is every time the list doubles, it briefly needs sufficient memory for *both arrays*. To add the next element to a list at a full capacity of a little over 2,146,400,000, we briefly need space for a little over 6,439,200,000 elements (the current array plus the new array, which is twice the size). Since .Net integers are 32-bits (4 bytes) each, **that's roughly 24GB of RAM.** Setting the capacity in advance will help here to ensure you need only 16GB RAM, which is still a lot, but it's not 24.

The next thing to understand is the difference between available memory and available **address space**. I've heard the garbage collector has gotten better at this since I last did a deep dive, but there's still a concern here. Your process may be able to use all the memory available on your system (and then some, thanks to paging), but it still has to address it. Running out of address space will also throw an OutOfMemoryException.

Every time the list doubles, when the garbage collector releases the RAM from the old internal array that RAM does go back to the OS, but there's a still a hole in the address space for the process. The garbage collector is able to clean these holes up through a process called "compaction", but it hasn't always been very good at this step, and even when it works that's another level of inefficiency. Again, setting the capacity in advance (if you know it) can really help.

---

But what if we could do even better. Let's look at an alternative. I suggest `Enumerable.Range()`:

```
var items = Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue - 10);
foreach(var j in items)
{
    if (j % 100000 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(j.ToString("N0")); 
    }
    // do something else with every j
}
```

The above code will have effectively the same output, and **uses less than 50 bytes of RAM** ( 4 bytes for `j`, 4 bytes for the `100000` constant, 4 bytes each for `MaxValue` and `10`, a 20 byte object reference to an internal `items` state machine, a 4 byte integer for the internal state machine's current state, and a 4 byte integer for the terminal state -- I may be missing something else, but it's small.)

### This is a savings of more than 515,000,000X !

In fact, it might not even use that much, if the compiler decides to use registers for any of those integers.

Even this much presumes a defined sequence of some kind. There's no reason we couldn't also use a traditional `for` loop, without a list or range at all, which would save even more.

---

**Update:**

> I may be missing something else, but it's small.

Yes, I'm missing the size of the "N0" format string (~28 bytes -- 20 byte object reference, 4 byte integer for the length, and two 2 byte unicode characters) and the size of each of the output strings, which must also exist in memory... but still only one at a time. I estimate the largest of these strings at 50 bytes, plus the 28 bytes for `N0`, means we're using about 122 bytes total. So the saving is **only a factor of 211 million. Only.**

But as a practical matter the garbage collector isn't going to clean up these string objects after every single loop iteration, so actual measured use will be up somewhat.

Comment: And then there are the performance benefits of not having to allocate and garbage collect 31 buffers, half of which will be allocated in the LOB heap, and copying their contents from one to another

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's the paragraph directly below the first code snippet.

Comment: There's no perf comparison though. I suspect a BDN output showing perf, memory and GCs would be very interesting. Especially the baseline column

Comment: Whatever BDN shows, the perf difference is infinite if the original code can't even finish :D

Answer (score 0):

Given the [List Capacity property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.capacity?view=net-6.0) accepts and returns an int, that may be a clue that List is limited to around 2,147,483,647 elements (although I have not found anything in the docs to verify this).

So, one solution might be to have a List of Lists, for example:

```
     const int k_list_size_max = 2;
     const int k_data_items_max = 2000000000;

     UInt64 total_items;

     List<int> data_items_list;

     List<List<int>> data_list = new List<List<int>>( k_list_size_max );

     total_items = 0;

     for ( int i = 0; i < k_list_size_max; i++ )
     {

        data_items_list = new List<int>( k_data_items_max );

        for ( int j = 0; j < k_data_items_max; j++ )
        {

           data_items_list.Add( j );

        }

        Debug.WriteLine( $"List[{i}] data_items_list.Count = {data_items_list.Count}" );

        total_items += ( UInt64 )data_items_list.Count;

     }

     Debug.WriteLine( $"Total items: {total_items}. " );
```

Output:

```
List[0] data_items_list.Count = 2000000000
List[1] data_items_list.Count = 2000000000
Total items: 4000000000.
```

Comment: Lists are limited by size of signed `int`. With some fiddling this can be expanded to `unsigned int`, but probably not as expected. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 0):

> What can be done to increase the memory allocated to C# and/or visual-Studio?

As your goal seems to be allocating memory, you can do that much better if you use larger structures. Just define a struct with a few doubles or guids and then make a list of these structs.

Then your 2 billion elements will easily use more than 32GiB.